# HTML - skip entire focus group when pressing tab

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a form with bunch of inputs.
Among them is a group of rare inputs which should not be focused when pressing tab.

However, when focus is already inside the group, pressing TAB key should move focus to next input within the group

```html
<input placeholder="Name" />
<input placeholder="email" />

<div tabindex="-1">
   <input placeholder="rarefield1" />
   <input placeholder="rarefield2" />
   <input placeholder="rarefield3" />
</div>
```

Is this achievable using HTML?

EDIT: demonstration of desired keyboard behavior

```js
function focusgroup(groupEl) {
  groupEl.addEventListener('keypress', keyEvt => {
    if (keyEvt.keyCode === 13 && keyEvt.target === groupEl) {
      focusFocusGroup(groupEl);
    }
  });
}

function focusFocusGroup(groupEl) {
  var inputs = [...groupEl.querySelectorAll('[tabindex="-1"]')];
  inputs.forEach(inputEl => inputEl.setAttribute('tabindex', '0'));
  inputs[0].focus();
  groupEl.addEventListener('focusout', e => {
    // If focus is still in the form, do nothing
    if (groupEl.contains(event.relatedTarget)) return;
    inputs.forEach(inputEl => inputEl.setAttribute('tabindex', '-1'));
  })
}


[...document.querySelectorAll('.focusgroup')].forEach(focusgroup);
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  width: 20em;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

.focusgroup {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
press tabs 3x and then enter
<input placeholder="commonfield1" autofocus/>
<input placeholder="commonfield2" />


<fieldset class="focusgroup" tabindex="0">
  <legends>group 1</legends>
  <input placeholder="rarefield1" tabindex="-1" />
  <input placeholder="rarefield2" tabindex="-1" />
  <input placeholder="rarefield3" tabindex="-1" />
</fieldset>
<br />
<fieldset class="focusgroup" tabindex="0">
  <legends>group 2</legends>
  <input placeholder="rarefield4" tabindex="-1" />
  <input placeholder="rarefield5" tabindex="-1" />
  <input placeholder="rarefield6" tabindex="-1" />
</fieldset>

<input placeholder="commonfield5" />
```

Comment: probably going to have to add a bit of JavaScript into the mix.

Comment: Question: how do I initially go into the group of fields ? I think you should rather think about a section that can be expanded or collapsed, it would be easier.

Comment: Having inputs which can be seen, and focused with the mouse, but not by the keyboard, is going to fail just about every set of accessibility guidelines out there. I suggest that rather than ask how to implement this, you come up with a better design.

Comment: @QuentinC: My idea was, that I make specific element focusable and by pressing enter the focus would enter the group

Comment: OK so that's almost what I thought about. Change your design to use a collapsable section, and put your rare fields in it. As previous comment already say it well, what you are trying to do at present is just inaccessible by design.

Comment: It would also break user expectation. If a keyboard user sees input fields, they'll expect to be able to TAB to all of them. It sounds like you're trying to treat the input field more like a radio group, which is one tab stop and you use the arrow keys to navigate between each radio button.

Comment: @QuentinC: Collapsible is not an option, because although the field are rarely edited, the values are still important for the user. Imagine address details based on selected customer.

Comment: @slugolicious: No, not like radiogroup. See my edit

Comment: Collapsible is not an option, because although the field are rarely edited, the values are still important for the user. Imagine address details ==> I don't see the point. Collapsible don't mean unreachable and invisible. IF I want to see or edit my address details, then I expand the section, that's not a big deal at all. And if I don't care right now I just don't expand and skip over. That's simple and everybody understands how it works.

Comment: The code snippet example helps provide additional details. Note that the example does **not** work with a screen reader. Pressing `enter` on the group does not make the input fields focusable. Without a screen reader, it works ok. This is another reason why your current idea should not be attempted. I get the gist of the idea, but I'm with @QuentinC about having an expand/collapse section for the "rare" fields. If you want the rare fields to always be displayed, then perhaps lump them together near the end of the form. Or have a "skip link" to jump over them.

Comment: Note, ironically, the "show code snippet" addition to your question is not keyboard accessible.  It's implemented with a link that doesn't have an `href` attribute, which makes it a "[placeholder link](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element:represents-2)" that you can't tab to. If I were a keyboard only user and couldn't use a mouse, I wouldn't be able to expand the code and run it. That's not your fault but is an accessibility issue with stackoverflow.com.  They have a mouse click handler on the `<div>` container of that link.

Comment: @slugolicious: Thank you, I'm a screen reader user and I was wondering why I couldn't open the code snippet. IF you confirm that it comes from SO and not the author of this question, then I think we should report the bug to meta, what do you think ?

Comment: @QuentinC, yes it's a SO issue. You can navigate to the main H1 heading to get to the question then nav to the "show questions" tags, which is a list of links. The first tag is HTML and if you arrow up from there you'll hear "show code snippet". NVDA will say it's clickable but JAWS won't. You can press ENTER to open the code snippet. There's a "run code snippet" button which is the next tab stop. Selecting that will open a small iframe with the code. You have to skip over the next two tab stops, "copy snippet to answer" and "hide results", to get to the iframe of the running code snippet.